# Add two array variables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am needing to get the sum value of two array variables.

Here's my code:

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($check);$i++){   
 for($j=0;$j<sizeof($item_rec);$j++){
  for($k=0;$k<sizeof($last_item_rec);$k++){ 

   //TOTAL_VAR = $item_rec[$j] + $last_item_rec[$k];

   $query=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE tblstock 
                            SET              
                               rec_qty='{{SUM VALUE HERE}}'
                            WHERE id = '$check[$i]'")
                      or die(mysqli_error($con));       
  } 
 }              
}//end for loop
```

As you can see in the comment, I don't know what variable will I declare to sum each array value of variable $item_rec and $last_item_rec.

Comment: You can declare the variable with `$` on the start like `$TOTAL_VAR` and cast the array value like `$TOTAL_VAR = (int)$item_rec[$i] + (int)$last_item_rec[$i]` or you can use float if the value is decimal.

Comment: @Roshan Hi thank you roshan, But I need to declare the TOTAL_VAR as array, because it will only output the last sum of $item_rec[$i] and $last_item_rec[$i]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `$i` variable in all nested `for` loops.

Change it to `$i`, `$j` and `$k`, for example.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that just only for typo error. But I will change it in actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi yes you will need to store the sum of two arrays in an array variable.

This code may help,

```
  for($i=0;$i<sizeof($check);$i++){   
   for($j=0;$j<sizeof($item_rec);$j++){
    for($k=0;$k<sizeof($last_item_rec);$k++){ 

       $TOTAL_VAR = array();

        $TOTAL_VAR = (int)$item_rec[$j] + (int)$last_item_rec[$k];

        $query=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE tblstock 
                                 SET              
                                   rec_qty='$TOTAL_VAR[$i]'
                                 WHERE id = '$check[$i]'")
                           or die(mysqli_error($con));       
       } 
      }              
     }//end for loop
```

Let me see if you can get through this.

Comment: Hi I tried it but it didnt show any output. Just a blank output.

Comment: I try to put additional nested loop  $TOTAL_VAR = array();
     for($l=0;$l<sizeof($TOTAL_VAR);$l++){

          $TOTAL_VAR = (int)$item_rec[$j] + (int)$last_item_rec[$k]; But it didnt sum up the value